# Angular sorting an array is disabling last control in formGroup

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sorting, angular-forms

I need to sort an array based on a control value (number type) from a formGroup inside another array:

```js
const toSort = [
  ['key2', FormGroup: {controls: {order: 2}}],
  ['key1', FormGroup: {controls: {order: 1}}]
  ]
```

I need to sort them so that a form shows the controls in that specific order. I have been able to sort it but somehow when I do it, when I submit the form the last control is not updating with the new value (the rest do). If I undo the sorting and the controls sort automatically in alphabetic order all the controls update their values correctly.

This is how I sorted the array:

```js
toSort.sort((val1, val2) => {
      return val1[1].controls.order.value - val2[1].controls.order.value;
    });
```

Any idea why is not working?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The problem was I was not assigning the sorted array to itself again after sorting.

```js
const toSort = [
  ['key2', FormGroup: {controls: {order: 2}}],
  ['key1', FormGroup: {controls: {order: 1}}]
  ]
  
 toSort = toSort.sort((val1, val2) => {
  return val1[1].controls.order.value - val2[1].controls.order.value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

please change

```js
val1[1].controls.order.value - val2[1].controls.order.value
=>
val1[1].controls.order - val2[1].controls.order
```

---

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

and have a look at orderBy filter

Comment: Change it like this?     toSort.sort(val1[1].controls.order.value - val2[1].controls.order.value => val1[1].controls.order - val2[1].controls.order);

Comment: @PabloG Yeah because there is no `value` key

Comment: I get an error saying Cannot find name 'val1' and same form val2

Answer (score 0):

Correct your sort function and try

and check ngForOf [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#description)

```js
const toSort = [
  ['key2', {FormGroup: {controls: {order: 2}}}],
  ['key1', {FormGroup: {controls: {order: 1}}}]
  ]

toSort.sort((val1, val2) => {
  return val1[1].FormGroup.controls.order - val2[1].FormGroup.controls.order;
});

console.log(toSort);
```

Comment: I edited the array. val1[1] and val2[1] are already the formGroups so I don't need to access them and I can call the controls directly.

Comment: Why don't you create an example on code sandbox to get better idea of your issue https://codesandbox.io/s/angular

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the code. This is a summary of the problem. The form is much more complex but in the end the problem is this when sorting